# DataGridViewButtonCell button color change on click

Tags: c#, button, datagridview, background-color

I have a `DataGridViewRow` that I add to a `DataGridView` "table" programatically. I want one of the cells to be a `DataGridViewButtonCell` so I can click on it. (I realize I can have a handler on the datagridview for *on_click* but I'd like to keep this way for simplicity of code).

I want to be able to set the forecolor/backcolor of a DataGridViewButtonCell.

```
DataGridViewRow dgvRow = new DataGridViewRow();
dgvRow = (DataGridViewRow)dgv.Rows[0].Clone();
dgvRow.Cells[0].Value = filename;
dgvRow.Cells[0].Style.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;

DataGridViewButtonCell dgvBtn = new DataGridViewButtonCell();
dgvRow.Cells[1].Style.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;
dgvBtn.Style.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;

dgvBtn.Style.BackColor = Color.Green; //this sets the color of the cell, not the button in the cell.
```

Q: How can I set the color of the button that appears in the cell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty much like with a regular `Button` you need to make it a `FlatStyle` `Button` to change the `BackColor`:

```
dgvBtn.FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Flat; 
dgvBtn.Style.BackColor = Color.LightGreen;
```