# Adjusting DatagridviewbuttonColumn width and color

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, datagridview

I have a datagridview Which displays data from database. I am adding a datagridviewbutton column at the end of the datagridview data programatically. I am making this button column as a delete button column. I have added a screenshot of my column. Here i cant decrease the width of the column. And also i want to change the color of the button to red.

[Sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/38G2e.jpg)

```
 DataGridViewButtonColumn Delete = new DataGridViewButtonColumn();
            Delete.Width = 2;
            Delete.HeaderText = "Delete";
            Delete.Text = "Delete";               
            Delete.UseColumnTextForButtonValue = true;
            dgv_listManufact.Columns.Insert(7, Delete);
```

here the delete.width not working. The width remains same. How to decrease the width? and the color too?

Comment: Is it FlatAppearance? [See here for the color!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37198297/datagridviewbuttoncell-button-color-change-on-click/37199514?s=10|0.7795#37199514) - What is this `Delete.Width = 2` supposed to achieve?? 2 Pixels?

Answer (score 1):

To change the color of the button use:

```
Delete.Style.BackColor = Color.Red;
```

Remember to change the `autosize` property of the column to false, this will allow you to change the width